# Swift UitableViewcell with button

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a strange behavior in the UITABLEVIEW.

I have a TableView with Button, what I wanted to do is when I clicked to a button in the tableView, I want the color border to change to red.

The problem is that the color is changing not only for the clicked button, but also for others row in the tableview:

Here is my implementation

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! chooseProductTVC 

    cell.Btn_AddProduct.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)


    return cell
}

@objc func btnAction(_ sender: MyButton) {

    sender.BorderColor = UIColor.red
    let point = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: tbl_View_ChooseProduct as UIView)
    let indexPath: IndexPath! = self.tbl_View_ChooseProduct.indexPathForRow(at: point)
     let object = self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
    print (object.produit_name)
    print("row is = \(indexPath.row) && section is = \(indexPath.section)")
}
```

As you can see in the picture below I have only clicked on the first button (Abricot) ==> other button has also automatically changed the border (Avocat) and many others.

[image]

Comment: Table view reuses cell thats why this problem is occurring. On button selection you can push text or selected item id in a array which contains the ids or text of selected items after that you need to reload table view. In cell for row if text is present in array then give border color as red else give blue color (or default color).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of cell dequeuing try to re set when you load the table ,  suppose here default is `blue`

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")  

  cell.Btn_AddProduct.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

  if selected

    cell.Btn_AddProduct.BorderColor = UIColor.red

   else

   cell.Btn_AddProduct.BorderColor = UIColor.blue

  return cell

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since we reuse the cell for displaying, we have to modify the color every time after dequeing.

Add new property `selected` to product model.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! chooseProductTVC 

    cell.Btn_AddProduct.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    let object = self.resultArray(at: indexPath.row)
    if object.selected
         cell.Btn_AddProduct.BorderColor = .red
    else
        cell.Btn_AddProduct.BorderColor = .blue

    return cell
}

@objc func btnAction(_ sender: MyButton) {
    sender.BorderColor = UIColor.red
    let point = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: tbl_View_ChooseProduct as UIView)
    let indexPath: IndexPath! = self.tbl_View_ChooseProduct.indexPathForRow(at: point)
    let object = self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
    object.selected = true
    print (object.produit_name)
    print("row is = \(indexPath.row) && section is = \(indexPath.section)")
}
```

Tip: You could use `tableChooseProduct`(iOS) instead of `tbl_View_ChooseProduct`.(android). This [link](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/) may helpful.

Comment: in fact I was ( in other life) a C# and VB .net developer. thank you for the tip

Answer (score 0):

You have to store `default Colors` in `Dictionary`.

```
var orderColor = [Int : UIColor]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

    for i in 0...29  // TotaL number of rows
    {
        orderColor[i] = UIColor.blue // DEFAULT color of the Button
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return 30
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! chooseProductTVC

   cell.Btn_AddProduct.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

   cell.Btn_AddProduct.BorderColor = orderColor[indexPath.row] 

   cell.selectionStyle = .none
   return cell
}


@objc func btnAction(_ sender: MyButton) {


   let point = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: tbl_View_ChooseProduct as UIView)
   let indexPath: IndexPath! = self.tbl_View_ChooseProduct.indexPathForRow(at: point)

    orderColor[indexPath.row] = UIColor.red

    tbl_View_ChooseProduct.reloadData()  

}
```